# adding std_msgs Int16 and int?

Tags: ros, python, ros-kinetic, msg, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i made a simple publisher which publish a Int16. the problem is in the subscriber i try to receive the int16 and add a constant number to it for example 2
the publisher code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int16
import random
def ty():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('to', Int16, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker1')
    r = rospy.Rate(1) # 1hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        value=random.randint(0, 100)
        print(value)
        pub.publish(value)
        r.sleep()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ty()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

the subscriber code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Int16

def cb(x):
    rospy.loginfo(x+2)
def listener():


    # In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
    # node are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
    # anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
    # name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
    # run simultaneously.
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("to", Int16, cb)
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

i got this error :

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Int16' and 'int'

how can i solve this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302524/adding-std_msgs-int16-and-int-?/) by [mohamed ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/37345/mohamed-ahmed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2018-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that `std_msgs/Int16` is not a simple `int` type but a Python class.

It contains a single field `data` that contains the actual `int`.

So for your code to work you should write:

```
rospy.loginfo(x.data + 2)
```

See [std_msgs/Int16](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Int16.html) for the documentation of the message type, and see [wiki/msg - Message Description Specification - Field Types](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification) for how those fields map to Python types.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mohamed ahmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/37345/mohamed-ahmed/) on 2018-09-07**:
thank you very much, it is my first time asking on ROS answers, i didn't expect such a fast response
thank you again it works for me